# SharePoint Online column hide issue

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Need to hide the sharepoint list columns for specific users without javascript
Site owner will be able to see all columns of that particular  list

Comment: Have you checked the following answer? If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use JavaScript to hide list columns based on user permissions, you can try to use PowerApps to customize the list form to hide the columns. There is a thread about this topic, you can refer to [it](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-Form-Hiding-fields-from-certain-Users/m-p/245685#M72104).

Note: This is not security, this is just hiding fields. A savvy user could use other means of modifying the list.

If you want the list is secure, it is recommended to create two lists for different users and set permissions based on your need.